# Google Calendar API. Search Events by multiple extendProperty Private by Or Condition

Tags: events, search, properties, google-calendar-api

In this post:
- https://developers.google.com/calendar/extended-properties I see:

"You can repeat these fields multiple times and the constraints are OR'ed together, so events only need to match one of the constraints to be returned. The following example finds events with either the private property `petsAllowed=yes` or `isOutside=yes`:"

But when I post array private key on `Events.List`. It must match all.
- https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list
"Extended properties constraint specified as `propertyName=value`. Matches only private properties. This parameter might be repeated multiple times to return events that match all given constraints."

How can I search with conditon "Or"?

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve? To list those events that have one or other extended properties?

Comment: yes, i just wanna list events that have one or other extended properties.

Comment: To what I believe private and shared properties can [only be AND ed](https://developers.google.com/calendar/extended-properties#searching) while public ones can be ORed. What are your properties, private or public? If you could also share a sample of your code or the way you are trying to achieve this could also be greatly helpful to give you some more advice. Thanks :D